# How to remove backslash from string in Python?

Tags: python, backslash

I need to remove backslash (`'\'`) from string in Python.

`str2 = str1.replace('\', '')`  isn`t working.

How can i do it?

Comment: You need to escape the backslash to make it literal.

Comment: `'\\'` is a string containing a single backslash. `'\'` is an incomplete literal, because the second `'` is _escaped_ by the backslash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to \ being the escape sequence character in python so you have to do \\

```
str2 = str1.replace('\\', '')
```

Answer (score -2):

There are 2 ways you can do that:

You have to escape the `\`:

```py
str2 = str1.replace('\\', '')
```

or using raw strings:

```py
str2 = str1.replace(r'\', '')
```

Comment: `r'\'` does not work.

Comment: A raw string still can't end with an odd number of backslashes per https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals.

Answer (score -2):

Little tricky but it works

```
str2 = str1.replace("\ ".replace(" ", ""), "")
```

Comment: this is needlessly complex

Comment: yes, but it works

Comment: Yes but that does not make it a good answer

Comment: Why would you want to replace a whole bunch of spaces when you can escape the backslash ```\\```

Comment: It just replace the space in the `\ ` and not whole bunch of space in the input string. I am giving alternative ways to do it with more logical expression, that works.